# OkHttp3 response.body().string() always returns empty

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView title;
    TextView instructions;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        title = findViewById(R.id.titleView);
        instructions = findViewById(R.id.instructionsView);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        String url = "https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/findByIngredients?number=1&ranking=1&ignorePantry=false&ingredients=apple%252Csugar%252Csalt";
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com")
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    Log.i("string", myResponse);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Log output for .toString(): 2020-05-04 19:55:51.801 9894-10024/com.example.testapi I/string: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@6314479

The Log output for .string(): 2020-05-04 20:00:39.430 10118-10143/com.example.testapi I/string: []

I know about how OkHttp3 is trying to empty the backing resource as soon as the first .body() call is made, but it's still empty for me.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please try to run in debugging mode and check the response. It's not the logs

Comment: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/findByIngredients?number=1&ranking=1&ignorePantry=false&ingredients=apple%252Csugar%252Csalt}

This is what I get when I check the response.

Comment: Is it expected response?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I get the 200 response code and that means the connection was made successfully. And the String should hold the body. There was no previous call to the body, so it should still be there. But it is not.

Comment: Which answer do you get when you try it the same call with curl or with postman?

Comment: even I am also facing same exact issue. is there any solution for this. please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Calling `response.body().string()` consumes the body - therefore, you can't call it the second time. In the **code outside of your snippet** , there must be at least one `response.body()` left.

> The response body can be consumed only once.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/index.html?okhttp3/ResponseBody.html

## Fix

Somewhere in your implementation code, `response.body()` is already called once. Instead replace by `response.peekBody()`.

The solution is to store it in a variable if you need it for further processing.

```
         @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String myResponse = response.peekBody(99999L).string();
                    Log.i("string", myResponse);
                }
            }
```