# Java REST endpoint returning response 200 but the body is blank

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a **REST Service** (Java 7) which I call via a **REST Client** (Java 11).

**Maven Dependency**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**REST Service**

```
@GET
@Path("trip/{tripId}")
@ApiOperation(value="Returns the details for a trip.")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code=200, message="Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code=404, message="Not Found")
})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getTripDetails(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("tripId") final String tripId)  {
    super.init(jwtTokenUtil, memberService, travelAgencyFacade);
    TripDetailsResponse tripDetailsResponse = new TripDetailsResponse();
    try {
        tripDetailsResponse.setTripId(tripId);
        final Long tripIdL = Long.valueOf(tripId);
        TripDTO tripDTO = trips.getTripDetails(tripIdL);
        tripDetailsResponse.setTripDTO(null);
        tripDetailsResponse.setStatus(ResourceConstants.SUCCESS_STATUS);
        Response response = Response.ok().entity(tripDetailsResponse).build();
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return handleError(e, logger, tripDetailsResponse, true);
    }
}
```

I test the REST Service in Postman, and it returns the following JSON as expected:

```
{
    "tripId": "1801855",
    "tripDTO": null,
    "messages": [],
    "status": "success"
}
```

**REST Client**

```
private Response callGETEndpoint(final String url) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = getTrustManager();
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .get()
            .build();
    okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    logger.info(url);
    try {
        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        return response;
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // try again
        try {
            Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            return response;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            logger.error("Call to "+url+" timed out.", ex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Call of the Client**

```
        Response response = client.callGETEndpoint(url);
        if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                final ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                final String responseString = responseBody.string();
```

**Problem**

The response does have a status of 200. However, the `responseString` is blank.  I would expect it to contain the  data seen in the Postman response.

**Question**

What do I need to do to get the body from the response?

Comment: My problem was I was already calling `resonse.body().string()` which removed the body.  Here is an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599751/okhttp3-response-body-string-always-returns-empty

Answer (score -1):

You can try this for parsing

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

....

ReadContext rContext = JsonPath.parse(response.body().string())